# Building 64 bit dll with MinGW 32 bit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dll, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I installed the 32 bit version of Mingw 4.7.2 (using the installer) on my Windows 7 64 bit. 
I use MinGW in an Eclipse C++ project in order to build a .dll file. So far everything works.

However I use this .dll to be included in a java project via JNI. And when I call a function of the .dll in the java project the exception `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\path\mylib.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"`
is thrown.
So it seem like I need to build an 64 bit version of the DLL.

So my questions are:

1. Can I build an 64 bit DLL with MinGW 32 bit or do I need the MinGW 64 bit version for that?
2. If yes how do I need to adjust the MinGW and/or Eclipse Settings to do so?

Regards Marc

Edit: As you can see in the comment below, I already tried to set the -m64 Flag to build a 64 bit dll. This results in the error: `"sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in"`.
So is there a way to get the 64 bit mode running in mingw32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem, installing the `MinGW-64` version enabled the `-m64` flag for me. You can get an automated build from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip/download).

**EDIT :** Some guy (`rubenvb`) made some good job in the `Personal Builds` :

There's gcc 4.7.4 [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.7-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.4-release-win64_rubenvb.7z/download) and even 4.8.0 [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb.7z/download).

Comment: Agreed, if mingw doesn't support it, mingw-w64 will do. +1 for the direct link.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the TDM-GCC compiler with a nice easy Windows installation from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/.

Then you can run the following to generate a 64-bit C Code Object file from the C Code Source File HelloWorld.c.

```
"C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe" -m64 -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\include\win32" HelloWorld.c
```

This should be run from the same directory as HelloWorld.c and will generate the HelloWorld.o file in that directory.  The `-m64` makes it 64 bit.  You can specify `-m32` to make a 32 bit object file and specify `-o`, to give the output as mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `-m64` switch to compile a 64 bit lib.

> These ‘-m’ switches are supported in addition to the above on x86-64
>   processors in 64-bit environments.
>
> -m32
>   -m64
>   -mx32
>       Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The -m32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code that
>   runs on any i386 system.
>
> The -m64 option sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer types to 64 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture. For Darwin
>   only the -m64 option also turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic
>   options.
>
> The -mx32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture.

( source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html )

**Example:**

**32 Bit:** `gcc -m32 -o exmaple32 example.c`

**64 Bit:** `gcc -m64 -o exmaple64 example.c`

*(same with `g++`)*

You can set them in eclipse: **`(right click on your project) -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings`**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried that, but when I want to build I get the error: "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in". So is there a way to get the 64 bit mode running with mingw32?

Comment: I see, but you can use the 64 bit fork of Mingw: MinGW-w64. Here's the official website: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/. But Golgauth has already posted a download link.