# How to run makefile in Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I have folder consisting files:

[image]

How to run makefile? In console I type:`make` and it says no makefiles found.

Comment: You are probably not in the right directory when running `make` - and thus it can't find the given "makefile". The current directory can be shown by typing in `pwd` and changed with `cd`. (The fact that running make generates that message means that a make program is installed by something, whatever it is.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a makefile in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use MSYS : http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS

> MSYS is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and
> grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on
> traditionally UNIX tools to be present.

This allows to run bash-like scripts under windows.

**MSYS** is included in `MinGW` package ([direct download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files)).

MinGW Shell :

[image]

NOTE : **[CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/)** can do this too, I think.

---

EDIT : The link to MinGW above is 32 bits. If you are interested in a 64 bits version of it, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16984116/1715716).

---

#### **EDIT :** Changes have been made and the Windows Installer now comes with a bunch of installable packages (quite similar to `apt-get install` under Debian). This comes with a GUI that allows to choose/customize additional tools. Download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download) (The link above is kind of deprecated).

Comment: I do not even know how to run it no EXE.

Comment: Added direct link to MinGW windows installer. Once MinGW installed, run the `MinGW Shell`.

Answer (score 5):

Your cmd was in the wrong directory.
Shift and right-click in the folder that has the makefile (not on the makefile though) and then type: `make` or if you have mingw: `mingw32-make`.

It should then work.