# GTK+ compilation undefined reference C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linker, gtk

I'm trying to compile and link a simple program downloaded from the web to learn how to make a GUI using the `gtk+` library.

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
BIN = gtk_led
SRC = main.c gtkled.c
OBJ = main.o gtkled.o

CPPFLAGS =-Wall -W -ansi -pedantic -O2 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(SRC)
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(SRC)
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ)

clean:
rm -f *.o *~ core $(BIN)
```

When I do `make`, the build fails with the following errors:

```
gtkled.o: In function `gtk_led_size_allocate':
gtkled.c:(.text+0x43a): undefined reference to `g_return_if_fail_warning'
gtkled.c:(.text+0x487): undefined reference to `gdk_window_move_resize'
gtkled.o: In function `gtk_led_size_request':
gtkled.c:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to `g_return_if_fail_warning'
```

So I don't understand why.... I'm new to Linux, so that's hard for me :)
(On ubuntu, working with virtualBox)

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better to show the command that `make` is running for you...

Comment: don't use -ansi -pedantic in your compiler flags. they are completely useless at best, or misleading and wrong at worst. use -Wall -Wextra if you want a decent set of modern compiler warnings from GCC. alternatively, look in the gcc man page and select the warnings that make sense for your code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use backquotes in `Makefile`-s (but use the [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) of GNU make). And GTK2 is obsolete, why not use GTK3?

Replace at least the two lines `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` with

```
 PACKAGES= gtk+-3.0
 OPTIMFLAGS=-g # put -O2 when all is ok
 PKG_CFLAGS= $(shell pkg-config  --cflags $(PACKAGES))
 CPPFLAGS =-Wall -W -ansi -pedantic $(OPTIMFLAGS) $(PKG_CFLAGS)
 LDFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PACKAGES))
```

BTW, you probably mean `CFLAGS` not `CPPFLAGS`. Run `make -p` to understand what are the builtin rules known to `make`; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) to some related questions...

Also, order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot, so

```
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ)
```

is wrong, you probably want

```
 $(CC) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
But that's not working... :/
I'm not sure that I need to have a complex makefile.
I found it with the source code.
But I have just main.c file and many libraries.
There isn't a simple way to compile this with a thing like this: 

all: hello

hello: hello.o main.o
 gcc -o hello hello.o main.o

hello.o: hello.c
 gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic

main.o: main.c hello.h
 gcc -o main.o -c main.c -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic

clean:
 rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
 rm -rf hello


Sorry, but I really don't understand makefile....

Thanks ! :)

Comment: What is not working? Show the exact commands run by `make`. And yes, when coding for GTK, you really want to learn how to write `Makefile`-s (or else, type the single command to build your application in the terminal, or make a shell script of it), because you'll quite soon will have several source files for your GTK app.

Comment: Thanks ! That's working by using  

    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN)

Thanks a lot ! :))

Comment: Then please upvote or accept my (improved) answer! BTW, you can use backquotes in comments; they have some special meaning (to typeset code).