# When I use "gcc" in makefile, after making it, I got a "cc" output

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

For example:

There are 3 source files {`main.c` `test1.c` `test2.c`} in the directory
and a directory file named `test3`,
and there is a source file named `test.c` in the directory of `test3`.

Now I want to create a makefile to compile and link these four source files.

And this is my Makefile:

```
# Cancel statement "CC=gcc"

src:=$(wildcard *.c) test3.c
obj:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src))

main:$(obj)
    gcc -o main $(obj)

.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm *.o *~
```

When I called `make` to compile them, I got a output like this：

```
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc    -c -o test1.o test1.c
cc    -c -o test2.o test2.c
cc    -c -o test3.o test3/test3.c
gcc -o main main.o test1.o test2.o test3.o
```

I know 'cc' is linked to 'gcc' in Linux.

What I don't understand is why did Make call `cc` to compile these four source files, but call `gcc` to link the object files?

Comment: I stongly advise you to modify your `clean` target by changing `*o` to `*.o`.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108)

Answer (score 5):

You changed one rule: the one that links the program `main` from the object files.  And when make did that link, you can see it used `gcc`.

You didn't do anything to change the built-in rules that make is using to compile the object files, so they use the default (the value of the variable `CC`) which is `cc`.

Comment: If the question is answered please click the checkmark next to the answer so it shows up as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

You wrote only the rule to link the object files, and allowed Make to use its default rule to decide how to build the object files from the source files.

GNU Make will expose its rules if you ask it with `--print-data-base`.  In this case, it tells us

```
%.o: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

and

```
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

and finally

```
CC = cc
```

This explains why Make uses `cc` to compile your C sources.  To change that, simply set `CC = gcc`.  Here's a complete Makefile which does that and also makes best use of Make's built-in rules, to help when you need to extend it:

```
src := $(wildcard *.c) test3.c
obj := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src))

CC = gcc

main: $(obj)
    $(LINK.c) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~
```