# How to recompile an existing linux application

Tags: linux, makefile, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking to edit and recompile the hcitool.c of bluez version 5.31. I installed the bluez 5.31 by following the procedure from the answer of this:
[Bluetooth Low Energy in C - using Bluez to create a GATT server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128586/bluetooth-low-energy-in-c-using-bluez-to-create-a-gatt-server)

In my trial, I duplicated the hcitool.c file and named it as myhcitool.c inside the tools folder and I use the command

```
gcc -o myhcitool.o myhcitool.c.
```

This gives me an error

```
myhcitool.c:43:27: fatal error: lib/bluetooth.h: No such file or    directory
 #include "lib/bluetooth.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried copying the myhcitool.c outside the tools folder and compile it there. That gave me a bunch of errors something like this:

```
/tmp/ccj1QmZK.o: In function `dev_info':
myhcitool.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `ba2str'
/tmp/ccj1QmZK.o: In function `conn_list':
myhcitool.c:(.text+0x501): undefined reference to `ba2str'
myhcitool.c:(.text+0x50f): undefined reference to `hci_lmtostr'
myhcitool.c:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `bt_free'
/tmp/ccj1QmZK.o: In function `cmd_dev':
```

I also tried editing the hcitool.c itself by modifying a simple printf in there and then redo the 'make' and 'make install' commands for the whole bluez. After that, when I tried running the hcitool, the modification that I did has no effect.

Comment: Have you done a `make clean` before?

Comment: no. And I just tried it now.

Comment: I just tried 'make clean' then redo the './configure', 'make' and 'make install'. My modification in the hcitool still does not take effect.

Comment: Applications have build systems and don't just consist of a single file. You can't just copy one file and compile it. Make your edits to the original file, and then run the standard configure/make/make-install sequence.

Comment: @davmac. If I get what you mean, I think that was what I did in one of my trials as I describe it in the end part of my question.

Comment: @d_air in that case I think you should re-write the question, explain exactly what you did and show what change you made. Also: where did you install to, and did you run the newly installed `hcitool` or just one that you had on your system previously? The standard location for binaries is usually `/usr/local/bin` unless you specify a different prefix to `configure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation errors clearly state that you are missing files and directories and that there are undefined references to types (since you are missing the files). You are copying a file outside of its directory and trying to compile it. This won't work as the includes (and more) required for it to compile correctly are missing.

- If you want to edit hcitool directly you should download the Bluez source, unpack it, `cd` into it and `./configure` it. The makefile will be generated and you can use `make` to build the executables. If you make change to the hcitool.c file you should make sure you recompile it and are running it inside the directory as `./hcitool` and not as general `hcitool` as this runs the executable installed to your system, rather than the one you edited.
- If you want to build it outside of the Bluez directory as a sort of standalone, you will have to copy all the files and folders defined in the `#include <x>` statements that are needed and make a separate makefile for those, since copying the existing one will probably not work.
- If you want to add a new file to the Bluez source, make sure you also make the correct Makefile edits so that it is included during compilation.

I'd like to add that `hcitool` has not been maintained for a long time and is on its way to being phased out of Bluez, so maybe you should take a different approach altogether!