# compiled C file not executable

Tags: c, linux, unix, compilation

So when I try to run a compiled C program on my school's "hercules" server, it runs as I would normally expect it to.  However, I've got an assignment that requires the use of forks, and running programs that fork on that server is forbidden, instead, I am to run them by remotely connecting to one of several Linux machines and running it there, from command line

However, any attempt to do so gives me this error:

```
shell2: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

Altogether, my command prompt looks like this:

```
a049403[8]% shell2
shell2: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
```

I've got the shell2 file in the working directory, when I type "ls" it shows it with the * character indicating it is notionally an executable.  I've tried setting its permissions to 777.  It produces the same error for other C programs which I have been working with and running, and "hercules" can run the exact same file without any difficulties or complaints.   My make file for this particular program looks like this:

```
all: shell2

Basics.o: Basics.c Basics.h
    cc -c Basics.c

doublinked.o: doublelinked.c doublelinked.h
    cc -c doublelinked.c

main.o: main.c Basics.h doublelinked.h
    cc -c main.c

shell2: main.o Basics.o doublelinked.o
    cc main.o Basics.o doublelinked.o -o shell2

clean:
    rm -f *o shell2
```

...and if I re-run the makefile it seems to build the program with no difficulties.

So, and reason an environment that can compile C programs would be unable to run them?  Any likely workarounds?

Comment: What does `file yourprog /bin/sh` say on the target machine?  If it doesn't say much the same thing, the trouble is what the error message says — your binary was prepared on a machine but is not executable on the machine where you're trying to run it.  It is not clear what 'hercules' means or which O/S it runs, but it appears to be incompatible with the Linux machines where you try to run it.  Do the compilation on the Linux machines, not on 'hercules'.

Comment: "hercules" running the exact same file (your words) means nothing if "hercules" isn't using the exact same executable format as your Linux machine. Delete the file, *then* `make clean`, then `make all` *on your linux box*.

Comment: You should install Linux on your own laptop....

Comment: I thought I had deleted everything and recompiled it all from Linux, but I did it again and it seems to be able to execute now, so thanks. Jonathan.

Answer (score 2):

First, your `Makefile` is not very good. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) to improve it. Always pass `-Wall -g` flags (to get all warnings and debug info) to `gcc` when compiling some home work.

Then, a possible explanation of why your binary program don't run on the target machine could be `libc` version mismatch. Or perhaps one system is 32 bits and the other is 64 bits. Use `file shell2` to find out.

I suggest to `make clean`  then recompile again (e.g. with `make all`) on the target machine.

Learn how to [**use the `gdb` debugger**](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a program compiled on a different (incompatible) architecture, you'll almost certainly run into troubles.

It's a little unclear from the question whether you're transferring and attempting to run the *executable,* or trying to build the executable from scratch on the new machine. It's also unclear whether your `make` (if you're running it on the new machine) is completely rebuilding everything.

However, given the `"Exec format error"`, it's a safe bet that the former case is the one you're encountering, trying to run an incompatible executable file.

So, here's my advice. Transfer everything to the new machine and execute:

```
make clean all
```

to ensure *everything* is being rebuilt.