# Linux : Glib was not found

Tags: c, linux

I have a sample C project that use GLib Library. In that source code, it use :

```
#include <glib.h>
```

When I compile, I found this error : "Glib.h : no such file or folder". I have google and find out that I should install this lib. So I use those command:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
apt-get install glade
```

After that, I have checked and see already exist this header file in my system: `usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h` But when I compile, I still meet problem above.

So I have change include line to :

```
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
```

So, after that, when I compile, I meet error inside `glib.h` header :

```
#ifndef __G_LIB_H__
#define __G_LIB_H__

#define __GLIB_H_INSIDE__

#include <glib/galloca.h>
#include <glib/garray.h>
// more code here
```

`glib/galloca.h : no such file or directory.` Because this error is inside system header file, I cannot modify anymore and still cannot compile.

I don't know how to fix this. I have read some post, that they change makefile. But, because my project is compiled automatically by IDE (CodeBlock) and I cannot really write a makefile, so that method doesn't suitable for me.

Please tell me a way to fix this.

Thanks :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58321/how-do-i-install-glib

Comment: @berkay this post as I have done. just install glib package. and i have installed it :(

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: sorry :( I have added this option to my IDE (by add -lglib) but still meet that error :( should i put version behind that (which version ?) or should I do some other things for my IDE (Codeblocks) understand it ? Thanks :)

Comment: I must admit I did that once, but it's some days ago.. I would suggest: `lglib-2.0`. If this is not working, follow the glib hello world examples. This should enlight you. (as me once a day :) This one: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-compiling.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There must be some problem with how you build. To compile C programs that use GLib, you need package `libglib2.0-dev`. You can either install it directly, or install `libgtk2.0-dev`, which pulls it in as a dependency. So you have the packages you need.

The correct way to compile a GLib program is to use `-I` with the path to the GLib include files.
An example (from [How to compile a helloworld GLib program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90338/how-to-compile-a-helloworld-glib-program) on askubuntu):

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) hello_glib.c
```

This should let you compile this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     GList* list = NULL;
     list = g_list_append(list, "Hello world!");
     printf("The first item is '%s'\n", g_list_first(list)->data);
     return 0;
}
```

The errors you are getting indicate that you are not setting the include path (`-I`) correctly. How to do this depends on your build system/IDE.

---

In Code::Blocks, you must set the include path and the linker options in the appropriate configuration dialog. Run `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`, which will output something like

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lglib-2.0
```

The directories after `-I` must be set in the compiler options of your project (should be under Project -> Build Options -> Search Directories), and the names after `-l` must be set in the linker settings. Another option is to create a Makefile, and let Code::Blocks use that.

See e.g.  [Q: What do I need to know when using 3rd party libs?](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29#Q:_What_do_I_need_to_know_when_using_3rd_party_libs.3F) in the Code::Blocks Wiki.

Comment: Poor answer for a person who was voting everybody down here.. A link to the ubuntu help page would have been enough, in comments of course. It remains the open question: `How to do this depends on your build system/IDE.` Good job!

Comment: @hek2mgl: Sorry if I ruined your day. I added some information about how to solve this in Code::Blocks. And I only voted you answer down because it proposed something that clearly coud not work. Anyway, now your answer is deleted, my downvote no longer counts against your rep (AFAIK). Also, feel free to add a better answer which gets more votes than mine :-).

Comment: No worry, my day is safe. :) I was about to click the delete button just in the moment you dropped that comment because I've used `apt-cache show libgkt2.0-dev`. Ok, I should have done this *before* attempting to answer the question. But imo a "hey you missed that ... " comment would have been enough...

Comment: in linker setting. I press add and add two directories after running above command (so appear in two line). about -lglib-2.0, does we need anything with this parameter ? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not alter your source code (e.g. the `#include` directives).

You just need to use [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) (both for compiling, with `--cflags`, and for linking, with `--libs`), preferably with a builder program like `make`.

[This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) for exactly your situation: a `Makefile` using `pkg-config` to compile some source program using *glib*