# Include GLib into CLion (Windows, Msys2)

Tags: c, cmake, clion, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to include GLib2 in my CLion C project on Windows. I have installed glib2.0 via pacman on Msys2. The include (`#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>`) get's recognized by CLion.

My problem is that the include's in the `glib.h` are not getting recognized.

Error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:10: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
   30 | #include <glib/galloca.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

But these 2 files exist on the filesystem:

```
glib-2.0/glib.h
glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(task_2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(BEFORE "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0" "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include")

add_executable(main src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(main ws2_32)
```

Comment: Did you install the 'dev' version of this package? See the response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21890576/3987854) question.

Comment: i am using windows.. Is there a dev version for windows?

Comment: Did you try installing [this](https://packages.msys2.org/package/glib2-devel?repo=msys&variant=x86_64)?

Comment: I just did, unfortunately still the same error.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you should change the include directory (potentially via CMake) to be this `C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0`. Based on your errors, it would seem the include directory is `C:/msys64/mingw64/include`.

Comment: That worked! But now I unfortunately get an "Undefined reference to `g_key_****`" for all glib-functions. Normally this shouldn't be that complicated, i don't know what i am doing wrong..

Comment: You need to **link** with `glib` library for use its functions. In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` command.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the compiler and linker flags for glib2 is via pkg-config, which is also available in MSYS2.
Please see: [How do I make clion work with following make and pkg-config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116037/how-do-i-make-clion-work-with-following-make-and-pkg-config)