# g++ consolidation: ld: fatal: file main.o: unknown file type

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, linker-errors

I'm scanning the web and all my project files for solution but still can't find the answer why my linker won't finish the job. Everything smoothly compiles into .o files, but the last make command fails. And here is the Makefile content:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -c
OBJS = main.o operacje.o porownaj.o 
dzialania: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

main.o: main.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

operacje.o: operacje.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

porownaj.o: porownaj.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *o
```

and again, here is the mistake that pops out:

```
g++ main.o operacje.o porownaj.o -o dzialania
ld: fatal: file main.o: unknown file type
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to dzialania
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `dzialania'
```

I'm sure it's some kind of a basic mistake but after staring at the file for a few hours I won't notice it anyway. Maybe some of you folks with notice the bug with a fresh eye.

btw. it's my first post after long-term passive lurking, I hope I did everything right. Thanks in advance!

@edit1 OK, I did all the suggested corrections

@edit2 Seems like the problem is caused by improper module division of my program. I'll rearrange it's structure and let you know if it works then. Thanks for all the support!

@edit3 OK, I changed the structure of my program and everything runs smooth, Thanks again!

Comment: Show more lines output by `make`

Comment: You seem to have lost some whitespace when posting your Makefile.  Make is very particular about whitespace.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I did all my previous makefiles in this fashion and I have no idea why this exact one doesn't work. I don't understand why main.o is considered an unknown type

Comment: Do `make clean` after changing your `Makefile` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$<` instead of `$^` in your rules to compile `main.o`, `operacje.o`, and `porownaj.o`:

```
main.o: main.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

operacje.o: operacje.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

porownaj.o: porownaj.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

That will cause make to compile only the corresponding `.cpp` file. When you use `$^` the header files are passed to the `g++` command which tells the compiler to create precompiled headers for them - that's what's ending up in `main.o` instead of the object file for `main.cpp`.

Comment: OK, tried it. This time I'm getting such thing:

g++ -Wall -pedantic -c  -o main.o
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `main.o'

If I try replace $< with corresponding source file names, the linker pops out a message that certain objects are multiply-defined. Each of my header files has a header guardian.

Comment: Post the output of `make --version`.  I've tried this with both GNU make 4.00 and 3.82.90.  I can reproduce your original problem when `$^` is used and I get a successful build when `$<` is used instead for the compile steps (note: the first instance of `$^` in the makefile is left alone because in that case we want all the object files to be passed to the link).  Of course, my `.cpp` files are simple single-function modules with `main.cpp` just calling the single function in the other files.

Comment: Multiple definition errors probably mean a bug in your program, not your makefile

Comment: I'll try to rearrange it then.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `make` variable definitions like `CC = g++`, or `CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic` etc.. should each be on its own line:

```
CC = g++ 
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic 
OBJS = main.o operacje.o porownaj.o
```

BTW, you probably mean

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic
```

You certainly don't want `-c` explicitly in your `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`; you really should remove it.

Also, recipes should be after its rule, so you want

```
dzialania: $(OBJS)  
    $(LINK.cc) $^ -o $@
operacje.o: operacje.cpp operacje.h porownaj.h  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

<sup>The several spaces are actually a single <kbd>tab</kbd> character.</sup>

Run `make -p` to understand the rules known by `make`; see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108).

Take time to read [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: oh, Makefile lines and tabs are OK in the Makefile, it happened in the copy-paste process. I did the suggested changes and it pops up the exact same error.

Comment: See the two answers I linked to. And show exactly the output of your `make` command (by editing your question as needed)

Comment: @user3408010: then can you fix the copy/paste in the question so the makefile shows correctly?

Comment: The recipe for `operacje.o` has the problem described in Michael Burr's answer it uses `$^` instead of `$<`