# g++ compiler option using `pkg-config...` results in -I(directory) What does the -I mean?

Tags: c++, linux

I am familiar with very simple g++ commands that compile and link programs, however when working with GTK+ I found the tutorial indicate that I should use `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

Now when I type in `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` to the terminal I get a list of libraries and files like this...

-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz

So my question is, what does the **-I** mean in front of a directory? For example `-I/usr/include/libpng12`

Comment: You probably should use a builder like *GNU* `make`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108)

Answer (score 2):

The `-I` flag is used to add directories to the list of directories to search for finding files in `#include <>` statements.

In your case, when a file is included by using `#include`, `/usr/include/libpng12` will be one of the directories in which the pre-processor will search for the file.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to experiment by making my own simple library containing 1 or two files...

So when I download a package like the one that is helping me with GTK, I am getting header files and then compiled binary of the .cpp files right?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the manual. All command line options are present there :-)

-I set the search path for libraries.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Answer (score 2):

`-I` is simply adding to the paths to be searched for header files. Note that these are searched **before** system paths.

You can find pretty much all the options for `gcc/g++` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html). In this case, you want the *Directory Search* options specifically; see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options). From that page:

> *-Idir*
>
> Add the directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be
>   searched for header files. This can be used to override a system
>   header file, substituting your own version, since these directories
>   are searched before the system header file directories. However, you
>   should not use this option to add directories that contain
>   vendor-supplied system header files (use -isystem for that).
>
> If you use more than one -I option, the directories are scanned in
>   left-to-right order; the standard system directories come after. If a
>   standard system include directory, or a directory specified with
>   -isystem, is also specified with -I, the -I option is ignored. The directory is still searched but as a system directory at its normal
>   position in the system include chain. This is to ensure that GCC's
>   procedure to fix buggy system headers and the ordering for the
>   include_next directive are not inadvertently changed. If you really
>   need to change the search order for system directories, use the
>   -nostdinc and/or -isystem options.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers from @R Sahu @Klaus and @Yuushi explain, the `-I dir` tells the compiler where to look for the `#include header.h` file.
When the program is compiled, it will be linked.  You will probably also need to tell the linker where to find the programs that support the functions in the #included headers.  This is done with the `-llibrary` flag. That is a lower case l not a one (1).
The pkg-config command references a set of files and will supply the compiler flags `--cflags` and link flags `--ldflags` if you supply the package name.

Put the returned -Includes before the source name(s) and the -l's after in your compile command request.

For other than casual, one-off programs, you should use make.  The cflag and ldflag info can be put in variables in the `Makefile` and referenced throughout your make script.

You can get a complete list of packages configured to pkg-config on your Ubuntu system with `locate *.pc`