# header file (.h) include problems with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use libxml2 to parse some XML files in C. To do this, after installing libxml2 developer package, I included this lines in my code.c file:

```
#include <libxml2/libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/tree.h>
```

Ok, so far so good... But when I compile the code,

```
gcc ../src/code.c -o App
```

I got this message by gcc:

```
/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:15:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
```

The parser.h file included in my code.c, isn´t finding your include path "libxml/xmlversion.h", and I got the error message.

I tried to compile passing the library path with the -I parameter, without success.

Please guys, how can I solve this?

Comment: Show your exact compilation command. I guess that some `-I` are missing, and probably `$(pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0)`

Comment: Need more information to help, how are you compiling it? Makefile? What is the build instruction that is failing?

Comment: My libxml2 files are in /usr/include/libxml2

Comment: No, they are in `/usr/local/include/libxml2/`

Comment: My compilation command is `gcc ../src/code.c -o App`

Comment: Please **edit your question** to put relevant details. If on Linux, install the *libxml2* development package.

Comment: @Constantinvs: You have a linker issue, add `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags libxml-2.0)` to your compile command, to tell the linker where the libxml headers are located.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: not a linker issue, a compiler one. He'll get the linker issue later!

Comment: @Constantinvs: use the `gcc -C -E` command to get proprocessed output; and add `-H` to your compilation commands to understand what is successfully included.

Comment: Thank you @BasileStarynkevitch, I added the `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags libxml-2.0)` to my compile command and I didn´t have the error anymore.

Comment: Edit your question again to show the exact compilation commands you are using....

Comment: That´s ok @BasileStarynkevitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if the `libxml2` is the system one (development package), it is probably known to `pkg-config` so the right way to compile and link (a single source file program) is:

```
 gcc -Wall -g $(pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0) \
     ../src/code.c \
     $(pkg-config --libs libxml-2.0) \
     -o App
```

Of course you'll need to simply `#include <libxml/parser.h>` etc... as [answered by alk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507605/841108)

You really should use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and have your `Makefile`, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) (to adapt to C instead of C++, so `CFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS` and `CC` instead of `CXX`...)

<sup>Take the habit to always compile with all warnings `-Wall` and debug info `-g` at least during the development phase.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#include <libxml2/libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/tree.h>
```

to

```
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
```

and add the option `-I/usr/local/include/libxml2` to the command you use for compiling.