# make not executing correct Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, igraph

I should preface this by saying I am very new to Makefiles.

I created the following Makefile:

```
all: tiling_graph.o
        g++ -o tiling_graph tiling_graph.o -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph
```

I am trying to make sure that -ligraph is included. However, when I type "make", I get the following output: "c++    -c -o tiling_graph.o tiling_graph.cpp"

Why is it not using the Makefile that I created in the current directory? I have tried using "make -f Makefile" and "make --file=Makefile" but none of these are working.

Also, right after I first made the Makefile, it worked correctly. The output after typing make was 
"g++ -o tiling_graph tiling_graph.o -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph"

I executed ./tiling_graph and it was successful.

Then I edited tiling_graph.cpp, ran make again, and the output was "c++    -c -o tiling_graph.o tiling_graph.cpp" and has been ever since.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Improve your `Makefile` by looking at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to think about a make rule:

```
target: dependency list
        commands to make the target
```

is that it is a recipe for making the file called `target` from the list of files in the dependency list. Since `make` can see the file system, it can tell whether any file in the dependency list is newer than the file named `target`, which is its signal for recreating `target`. After all, if none of the dependencies have changed, the target must be up-to-date.

Note that `make` knows quite a lot about how to build files. In particular, it has a lot of built-in "pattern" rules, so it knows, for example, how to make an object file (`prog.o`) from a C++ source file (`prog.cpp`) or from a C source file (`prog.c`) or many other things. So you only need to actually write a makefile when you have other requirements, like a library (and even then you could just add that to an environment variable, but the makefile is better).

Now, you don't actually want to build a file called `all`. You want to build a file called `tiling_graph`. So the correct make rule would be:

```
tiling_graph: tiling_graph.o
        g++ -o tiling_graph tiling_graph.o -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph
```

Since `make` already knows how to create `tiling_graph.o`, it can actually figure out how to make `tiling_graph` from `tiling_graph.cpp`.

So where does this `all` come from? The usual way to use `all` is:

```
all: program1 program2 program3
```

which tells `make` that the `all` target requires `program1`, `program2` and `program3`. So if you need to build all three of those programs, the `all` rule would let you just do one `make` command. Since there is no file named `all`, that's a "phony" target and (with gnu make, at least) it should be declared as a phony target:

```
all: tiling_graph
.PHONY: all
```

But you really don't need that if you just want to build one program.

When you just type `make` (as opposed to `make target`), `make` chooses the first target in the makefile. So if you put the thing you usually want to build first, you'll save some typing.