# Make Does Not Update Executable

Tags: c++, makefile

I have written the following makefile:

```
CC=g++

all: happy

happy: happy.o HappyLetter.o
        $(CC) -o happy happy.o HappyLetter.o

happy.o: happy.cpp
        $(CC) -c happy.cpp

HappyLetter.o: HappyLetter.cpp
        $(CC) -c HappyLetter.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf *.o happy
```

and am working with the files HappyLetter.cpp and happy.cpp (which includes the former) to create an executable named happy.

I can build the code successfully using make. However, when I modify HappyLetter.cpp and type 'make' again, the change is not reflected. It only works when I type 'make clean' and then 'make'. The update of the object file that I expect to take place is echoed to the command line:

```
$ make
g++ -c HappyLetter.cpp
g++ -o happy happy.o HappyLetter.o
```

However, the update to HappyLetter.cpp is not being reflected in happy.

The problem does not work in the other direction. That is, if I modify happy.cpp, the change is reflected immediately after I type 'make'.

I have replicated this problem with three make binaries on my Mac OS X, and also on an Ubuntu machine. So I must be doing something wrong in the coding. Here is the text of the files, which are in the same directory as the makefile:

happy.cpp

```
#include "HappyLetter.cpp"

int main()
{
  printf("Hello from happy.cpp!\n");
  HappyLetter *myObj = new HappyLetter();
  myObj->speak();
  return 0;
}
```

HappyLetter.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>

class HappyLetter {
  public:
    void speak()
    {
      printf("Hello from HappyLetter.cpp!\n");
    }
};
```

I believe the problem is something simple, but I have no more ideas about what to check. One assumption I have is that the ordering of the rules and dependencies does not matter.

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` or `make --trace`; also improve your `Makefile` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108); try also `touch HappyLetter.cpp` before re-running `make`

Comment: You should *not* `#include "HappyLetter.cpp"` near start of `happy.cpp`; you should have a `happy.h` header file, have `#include "happy.h"` in both `HappyLetter.cpp` and `happy.cpp` and modify your `Makefile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>As I commented:</sup>

First, you should (conventionally) not `#include "HappyLetter.cpp"` in your `happy.cpp` (even if that is doable but poor taste). You should have a *separate* header file (with the conventional [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard))

```
#ifndef HAPPY_INCLUDED
//// file happy.h
#define HAPPY_INCLUDED 
  class HappyLetter {
 public:
   void speak();
 };
#endif /*HAPPY_INCLUDED*/
```

<sup>(You may -or not- decide to e.g. `#include <cstdio>` in your `happy.h` before the `class HappyLetter`; there are good reasons to do both ways!)</sup>

Then you should have a first source file:

```
// file happy.cpp
 #include <cstdio>
 #include "happy.h"
int main() {
  printf("Hello from happy.cpp!\n");
  HappyLetter *myObj = new HappyLetter();
  myObj->speak();
  delete myObj;
  return 0;
}
```

<sup>BTW, you should use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)!</sup>

Then you have your second source file:

```
 // file happyletter.cpp
 #include <cstdio>
 #include "happy.h"

 void HappyLetter::speak() {
  printf("Hello from HappyLetter.cpp!\n");
 }
```

At last, a `Makefile` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) for inspiration), like:

```
 # file Makefile
 CXX= g++
 CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g
 RM= rm -f
 .PHONY: all clean

 all: happy-prog

 clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ happy-prog

 happy-prog: happy.o happyletter.o

 happy.o: happy.cpp happy.h
 happyletter.o: happyletter.cpp happy.h
```

Notice the explicit dependency on `happy.h` header

As I commented, consider using [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)`-x` or `make --trace`  to debug your `Makefile`. Notice that GNU make has a lot of built-in rules, run `make -p` to get them.

Read more about [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), notably a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/), a good [programming in C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) book, have a glance into the standard (e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) draft). Read also about [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), notably [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Study the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) coded in C++ (see [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [github](http://github.com/) etc... to find one).

<sup>(so you got both your C++ source files and your `Makefile` wrong!)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the polite and thorough answer! My problem is solved. I will follow up on your recommendations for study.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you learning programming with C++ or was you taught programming in some other language?