# Makefile Dependencies, What Should Be a Dependency?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a conceptual question regarding makefile dependencies and this is because I see inconsistency online about this.

Let's say I have the following files:

```
main.cpp         uses->     my_math.cpp and my_strings.cpp
my_math.cpp      uses->     my_math.h
my_strings.cpp   uses->     my_strings.h
```

If I have a makefile, with the general outlay of:

```
program: $(all_objs)
     g++ $(all_objs) -o program
main.o: ...
     .......
my_math.o: ...
     .......
my_strings.o: ...
     .......
```

I don't know what should go into each dependency. Like, math.o #includes my_math.h and my_strings.h, does that mean that main.cpp needs to recompile if I change my_math.h? But why? It uses it like a library, right? It doesn't need to recompile main.cpp or does it?

As in, should the result for main.o be:

```
1) main.o: main.cpp
         gcc -c main.cpp

2) main.o: main.cpp my_strings.cpp my_strings.h my_math.cpp my_math.h
         gcc -c main.cpp

3) main.o: main.cpp my_strings.cpp my_strings.h my_math.cpp my_math.h
         gcc -c main.cpp my_strings.cpp my_math.cpp
```

I'm a bit lost on dependencies and how linking works.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you take the time to read documentation of the usual tools (`make` & `g++`) that you are using?

Answer (score 7):

The dependencies are everything whose change requires recompiling the source code. That includes not only your `#include`-d headers, but also the *indirectly* included system headers, and even (in principle) the compiler and build chain itself (when you upgrade your C++ compiler, you should recompile all your software). If some of your C++ code is generated from some source (e.g. by tools like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or Qt [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html), or by your own script), both the sources and the generating tools are dependencies. Read also about [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Practically speaking, the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is able to output most `make` dependencies, notably with `-M`  and related [processor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html). Read also about [auto dependencies generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394609/841108).

<sup>(in practice, you generally don't code in your `Makefile` some explicit dependency on the compiler itself; but you should not forget to `make clean` when the compiler has been upgraded)</sup>

Unless your `main.cpp` is including `my_strings.cpp` (which is not conventional and is very bad taste), your `make` rule won't have a dependency from `my_strings.cpp` to `main.o`. But probably your `main.cpp` is `#include`-ing (directly or indirectly) `my_strings.h` so `main.o` should depend not only on `main.cpp` but also on `my_strings.h`

As a rule of thumb, your object file `my_strings.o` depends on the source file `my_strings.cpp` and all the *header files* which are directly or indirectly `#include`-d in it. Your main `program` executable depends on all its object files and the libraries you are linking into it. Order of program arguments to `g++` matters a lot.

> It uses it like a library, right?

From what you are showing, you don't have any own [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) (but you probably use the standard C++ library, and perhaps some other system libraries). On Linux these are `lib*.a` files (static libraries) or `lib*.so` files (shared libraries). A library is an organized agglomeration of object code -and sometimes other resources.

> I'm a bit lost on dependencies and how linking works.

Understand the difference between [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) files, [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (they contain [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) information) and [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (on Linux, object files and executable files and shared libraries are using the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format). Read also about the role of [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (the `g++` program can run both) & [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (for which you are using `make`).

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and much more about [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit) and [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) (& [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)), notably Levine's book on [Linkers & loaders](http://iecc.com/linkers/).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28158290/841108) (examples about `Makefile` for C++ programs).

BTW, you should use `g++` (not `gcc`) when compiling C++ code. There are significant differences (even if `gcc` is *sometimes* able to compile C++ or Fortran code, you'll mostly use `gcc` to compile C code). And (assuming you use specifically GNU make) your `Makefile` should mention `$(CXX)` (not `g++`). You need to understand the builtin rules of `make` (run once `make -p` to get them) and you'll better take advantage of them (e.g. use `$(COMPILE.cc)` or `$(COMPILE.cpp)` etc...). You certainly should pass `-Wall -Wextra` (to get all warnings, and even more), and `-g` (to get debugging information) to `g++`. Practically speaking, you should set your `CXXFLAGS` variable in your `Makefile`.

Take time to carefully read [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Look into the `Makefile`-s of existing free software projects. For various reasons, some projects are *generating* their `Makefile`-s with tools like `autoconf` or `cmake`. But most simple projects don't need that generality, and you should be able to write your own `Makefile` for your C++ projects. Of course, take inspiration from existing code.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very in-depth post! I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
main.cpp         uses->     my_math.cpp and my_strings.cpp
my_math.cpp      uses->     my_math.h
my_strings.cpp   uses->     my_strings.h
```

The purpose of Make is to maintain dependency between modules in two different ways, by building .o files and by linking .o files.

you can picture it as a dependency tree where main.o is the root

```
                         main.o 
                       /       \
                   my_math.o   my_strings.o
```

for each .o there is also a dependency tree with regard to source files e.g.

```
    main.o               my_math.o               my_strings.o
   /      \              /        \              /           \ 
main.cpp   main.h     my_math.cpp  my_math.h  my_strings.cpp my_strings.h
```

So when make builds, it sets up a dependency tree with main.o at its root and then tries to build all .o files needed for main. When all .o files have been built they are linked.

By following the dependency tree Make ensures that main will be linked/built when one of the dependent modules is changed.

However if you have used something like say a constant from one of the included headers `#define MAXSTRING 32` you are no longer merely dependent on the .o file, you are then dependent on the header content so you need to make sure that main.o is built if the header is changed since linking is then not enough so you add the .h in the dependency

```
                               main.o 
                            /     |     \
                   my_math.o my_strings.o my_strings.h
```

Of course there are ways to make the header more robust to avoid that dependency but is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cpp` files do not depend on other `cpp` files in terms of compilation. Simple `cpp` file should only depend on `h` files.

In your question you say `main.cpp` depends on `my_math.cpp` and `my_strings.cpp`, but I think it is not true. I can guess you have `#include`s there and these are your dependecies.

Generally speaking dependencies for `cpp` files are all `#include`d `h` files.

Usually there are no dependencies between `cpp` files. You just generate `o` files by compiling them. Then your final binary depends on all `o` files.