# Makefile not getting updated

Tags: c, makefile

I have following files-

```
maze: maze.c
    gcc -o maze createMaze.c findcheese_iter.c maze.c -I.
```

Even after making changes to `createMaze.c` when I try running `make` command in the terminal,it says `make: 'maze' is up to date.` As a result I am not getting the correct answer.When I run the same code by this way it runs-

```
gcc createMaze.c maze.c  findcheese_iter.c -o exe
```

Comment: Typo: `createmaze.c` vs `createMaze.c` ; and that might explain everything!

Comment: No sry it isnt a typo,I wrote it wrong here.I have editted my question

Comment: Your `Makefile` is wrong.  See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) for inspiration (but use `CC` instead of `CXX` etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your problem is that you have set the dependencies for `maze` to be only `maze.c` and when you update `createMaze.c` you are not updating any of the dependencies.

You should add all the files the output-binary actually depends on, to the depend list.

E.g.:

```
maze: createMaze.c findcheese_iter.c maze.c
    gcc -o maze createMaze.c findcheese_iter.c maze.c -I.
```

Answer (score 1):

change your makefile to the following:

```
maze: maze.c createMaze.c findcheese_iter.c
    gcc -o maze createMaze.c findcheese_iter.c maze.c -I.
```

make will just compile, when the targets right behind the doublepoint changes...

Comment: why not put `findcheese_iter.c` also in the dependency list?

Comment: While you're very right, I was just trying to make the point of the purpose for the dependency list.