# make file for Gtk

Tags: makefile, gtk, gtk3

I have a make file, which creates obj files for all source files and then the executable using those obj files (basically compiling each individual file and then linking all of them together).

```
CC = gcc
SRC_DIR = src
INC_DIR = inc
OBJ_DIR = obj
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)
EXE = project

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(SRC_DIR)/file1.c            # and so on...
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(OBJ_DIR)/file1.o            # and so on...

main : clean build

build:  $(OBJS)
    $(CC)   $(OBJS) -o $(EXE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I tried to do the same for gtk+3.0 but haven't been successful as the examples on the web always have been with respect to the example file and not the project as a whole (consisting multiple source files). one such eg:

```
$ cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` hello.c -o hello
```

Make file for gtk+ is:

```
CC = gcc
SRC_DIR = .
INC_DIR = .
OBJ_DIR = Obj
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -o
PACKAGE = `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
EXE = Gui

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/main.c 
OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o 

main : clean build       

build: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(EXE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(PACKAGE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But this doesn't work. It gives errors (undefined reference to 'gtk_init' and other gtk functions)
What modifications should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *CFLAGS* must have ***-c*** or that must be included while compiling. Also, the pkg-config must be included during linking.

After the changes, the make file becomes:

```
build: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(EXE) $(LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ***-c*** -I$(INC_DIR) $< -o $@ $(PACKAGE)
```

The changes run successfully.

Comment: I found this later, but here is a very good explanation.
http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/09/glade3-tutorial-6-signals.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 LDLIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

instead of `LIB`

Check with `make -p` your builtin rules.

Look also at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108). See `$(LINK.o)` variable, etc.

Comment: but i haven't used LIB

Comment: And `LIB` is unknown by builtin rules, so your `LIB` is wrong.