# C programs linked with library

Tags: c, makefile, jansson

I am trying to link a Library to my C program but I can't make it work
according to the library doc https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#compiling-and-installing-jansson all I have to do is put 
`pkg-config --cflags --libs jansson` after GCC in the Makefile, but I get the following error :

make -C `pkg-config --cflags --libs jansson` src
make: invalid option -- '/'
make: invalid option -- 'u'
make: invalid option -- '/'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...

Comment: That isn't how you're supposed to use `pkg-config`, like you say yourself it needs to be added when invoking the compiler, not make. Please add your makefile to provide a [mcve]

Comment: still new to makefile, I thought gcc was incoked with make, I just posted the Makefile

Comment: In general, you can't do something with Make unless you know how to do it *without* Make. It looks as if the correct compiler command is "cc -o prog prog.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs jansson`", but you must confirm this before you try to build a makefile around it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108 is an answer to a very similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Makefile do something like this:

```
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs jansson)
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags jansson)
```

Then, inside your targets (where you compile/link your code) use it following way:

```
cc ... $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS)
```

If you are looking for `Makefile` sample, take a look here:

http://www.owsiak.org/fortran-and-gnu-make/

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but it should give you some ideas about `Makefile` structure, targets, wildcards, etc. It's `Fortran` based, but I am pretty sure you can easily read it.