# mingw-w64 installer "the file has been downloaded incorrectly"

Tags: installation, mingw-w64

I am trying to install mingw-w64 onto Windows. However I receive an error, "the file has been downloaded incorrectly". Redownloading the setup file again from sourceforge does not fix the problem. Is there an alternative way to install it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I suggest trying the manual method outlined here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite I had the same issue and that's what I did. You can also try this setup tool http://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe I had issues with both tools hence the manual way which is very painful. Goodluck.

Comment: I had the same problem but chaning version to the second newest (from 7.3.0 to 7.2.0) solved it

Comment: I couldn't execute from download folder in win10, copied the exe file to c/temp and executed from there fine

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Old post but same problem, the installer doesn't seem to work.

I give the solution which works for me

You can directly download the archive of MinGW64 with your chosen configuration :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/

Once the compressed file downloaded, you have just to extract and copy/paste the MinGW64 folder( with the pre-compiled librairies) to your chosen folder ( in my case : C:\mingw64)

Comment: In which folder are the pre-compiled libraries?

Comment: At https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/ you can find platform specific setup downloads under MinGW-W64 GCC-x.x.x. For me (Win 7-64bit) "x86_64-posix-seh" worked,

Comment: would be nice to know how you setup de environment variable

Comment: Did't find bin folder in this method.  Timur Turbil's answer works for me.

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated and have not worked for many years.

Answer (score 47):

I got same error and solved it, after struggling a few hours. You should download MinGW64 via https://winlibs.com/#download-release.
[image]

After downloading, You should unzip mingw64 file to a folder(in my case I unzipped it to c disk; C:\mingw64)

And then you have to set up path. for that follow below steps;

1. open settings.
2. Search for Edit environment variables for your
   account.
3. choose path variable and then select edit.
4. Select New and add the Mingw-w64 folder path(bin folder). In my case, I added (C:\mingw64\bin).
5. Select OK to save the updated path.
   And reopen your cmd, then check if everything is good by typing; **gcc --version**

Comment: Worked for me but I installed tghe Zip Archive and not the 7-Zip

Comment: Very nice, it worked!

Comment: This method looked sketchy, but it indeed worked and I recommend it as a solution. If winlibs didn't have a few things to help me validate it, I woulda avoided as possible virus....even then I still see this as taking a chance. It had a wiki page which granted credibility, but even a fake wiki page and multiple fake variable downloadable releases on the main site wouldn't surprise me at this point.

Comment: Thank you.  All the other methods did not work.  You linked to the correct URL to simply unzip it and build a path variable.

Comment: the only one who worked for me.

Comment: This one workes, people get confused because there is another download on Source Forge that downloads some installation in a zip, and there is no bin file and stuff inside. This is a helpful one!

Answer (score 12):

Long story short, **the official installer is broken** and not been fixed for years, so we have to install it manually.

---

[image: installer_download_link]

The **official download link** above would bring you to *sourceforge*: `https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains targetting Win32/Personal Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe`

And in the same [folder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/) that contains the installer, there's a `repository.txt`. ([about this file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113943/8140473))
[image: repository]

Take a look at it, the installer basically just download and unzip the build from one of these urls within `repository.txt`. Choose the url you want and download/upzip it manually. (In my case, I use `8.1.0|x86_64|posix|seh|rev0` setup)
[image: repository.txt]

Last, setup the `Path` environment variable pointing to your unzipped bin folder, let say `C:\mingw64\bin`, and this should do the trick.

Comment: Great answer. I do have one question however. Which environment variable? PATH?

Comment: This is the only correct answer, because it installs exactly what the installer would. The other answers install some other MinGW-w64 distributions that may or (more often) may not work for the intended purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I solved this problem by downloading this:http://winlibs.com/

GCC 10.1.0 + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 10.0.0 + MinGW-w64 7.0.0 - release 3   (LATEST)
Win32: 7-Zip archive* | Zip archive
Win64: 7-Zip archive* | Zip archive

and set the %path%

After that, I still can't execute gcc correctly, but then I solved the problem by adding this environment variable:

> "CGO_ENABLED=1"

I encountered the problem when using this golang package: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3

Comment: This ([file downloaded incorrectly](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/webdev/mingw-file-downloaded-incorrectly)) is one of the best tutorial on the subject as it points out the only solution that worked for me. And its [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcy981HhGw0) counterpart here.

Answer (score 2):

Following this tutorial helped me manually install MinGW for windows : [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWC5fVk0QqE&t=187s&ab_channel=BoostMyTool)

So the problem for me was that when I tried to use the `.exe` installer, it either showed me that,
"*the file has been downloaded incorrectly"* , or , the `/.../bin` folder did not have any files in it.

In the link above,  the MinGW files (including the `/bin` files) were manually downloaded and identified properly by the `Environment Variables`.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. When I re-ran the installer **as an adminstrator** it was installed successfully.

I also made sure not to add any spaces to the installation path.

Comment: I both ran the installer as an administrator and made sure that the path didn't have any spaces, it didn't fix it for me unfortunately.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is with your internet connection and/or ISP. I'm not great at networking so I'll let others be more specific. I tried installing/downloading it using my mobile's data as wifi hotspot and it worked. Hope it helps

Comment: I was able to solve it by following this [how to properly install mingw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcy981HhGw0) video tutorial. It's not an internet issue. I struggled with this a bit, redownloaded the file, etc