# How to install MinGW64 (non of the approaches work)

Tags: windows, mingw-w64

I am trying to install MinGW64 on Windows 10. Here is what I tried:

## Approach 1

*Via http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php*

I went to http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/win-builds and from there to http://win-builds.org/doku.php/download_and_installation_from_windows where I downloaded Win-builds 1.5.0. I run the exe and let it install everything. When it gets to install mingw64 it says that the Download failed (no further information). What should I do?

## Approach 2

*Via https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/*

I also downloaded mingw-w64-v7.0.0 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/, extracted the zip but have not idea what to do with the contents:

```
13.02.2020  13:37                   .gitignore
13.02.2020  13:37            31.032 aclocal.m4
13.02.2020  13:37             2.398 AUTHORS
13.02.2020  13:37    <DIR>          build-aux
13.02.2020  13:37               625 config.h.in
13.02.2020  13:37           123.961 configure
13.02.2020  13:37             3.268 configure.ac
13.02.2020  13:37             2.326 COPYING
13.02.2020  13:37    <DIR>          COPYING.MinGW-w64
13.02.2020  13:37    <DIR>          COPYING.MinGW-w64-runtime
13.02.2020  13:37             2.245 DISCLAIMER
13.02.2020  13:37               454 DISCLAIMER.PD
13.02.2020  13:37               745 Makefile.am
13.02.2020  13:37            25.337 Makefile.in
13.02.2020  13:38    <DIR>          mingw-w64-crt
13.02.2020  13:38    <DIR>          mingw-w64-doc
13.02.2020  13:39    <DIR>          mingw-w64-headers
13.02.2020  13:39    <DIR>          mingw-w64-libraries
13.02.2020  13:39    <DIR>          mingw-w64-tools
```

## Approach 3

*From: [mingw-w64 installer "the file has been downloaded incorrectly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455927/mingw-w64-installer-the-file-has-been-downloaded-incorrectly)*

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/48519212/4533188 it was said that should download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/, so I went there downloaded `MinGW-W64-install.exe` and ran it. The post says further

> Once the compressed file downloaded, you have just to extract and copy/paste the MinGW64 folder( with the pre-compiled librairies) to your chosen folder ( in my case : C:\mingw64)

but I got a lot of files installed to `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\`. So I copied the files of the folder to `C:\MinGW64`, but it seems I still do not have it installed.

## Approach 4

*From [How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)*

I went to https://www.msys2.org/, downloaded the `x86_64` version, went through the steps outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800825/4533188 - except for point 7. which I substituted with running `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`. This seems to have worked, but the folder `C:\MinGW64` is empty and running `gcc.exe --version` says, the command could not be found. I have no idea where msys2 installed what and how I have to link/move what to get gcc to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following approach did work for me. I got there via the link in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113943/4533188

1. Got to https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/
2. Click on the newest version (e.g. [8.1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/))
3. Click on [x86_64-posix-sjlj](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/sjlj/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0.7z/download)
4. Download the 7z-Archive

Alternative way of clicking around:

1. Got to https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
2. Click on [files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)
3. Click on [x86_64-posix-sjlj](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/sjlj/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0.7z/download) of the version you want
4. Download the 7z-Archive

Then:

5. Unzip the archive
6. Inside it there is the folder `mingw64` - move it (and its contents) into `C:\MinGW64`
7. The gcc can be found at `C:\MinGW64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe`

Comment: also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer), sjlj might not be the best option

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your approaches:

- **Approach 1** - the win-builds site is out of date and should not be used now.
- **Approach 2** - you downloaded source code, only do this if you are set up to build from source.
- **Approach 3** - it sounds like you installed it correctly and it is unclear why you feel it is not installed. NOTE - this approach goes more smoothly if you choose the option "MinGW-W64-install.exe" instead of unpacking a zip file; this will also install batch files to the start menu which set up the environment for Windows Command Prompt .
- **Approach 4** - again it sounds like you installed it correctly but have a faulty expectation about the install path. MSYS2 packages will go underneath the MSYS2 root directory. And it is not clear where you typed "gcc.exe"  (you should just type `gcc` from the MSYS2 mingw-w64 shell, which will be accessible from start menu and desktop shortcut if you chose that during the MSYS2 install), and you probably do not want to skip step 7 (CMake relies on gmake; you could install cmake in addition to make).

For approach 4, [this list of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/1505939) is slightly better than the list you linked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing MINGW-W64.
What I did was to **Run as Administrator**, make sure the installation path contains no **spaces**.

Initially, I was installing it at `C:/Program Files (x86)/Mingw-w64` so I change to install it directly on `C:/Mingw-w64`

Answer (score 0):

**Method to switch from MinGW-w32 to MinGW-w64**

- <s>[Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) the executable file of MinGW-w64</s> Refer the EDIT

(Executable file link may change for future releases, this is for Version 8.1.0, Kindly cross verify the latest version before installing from this link)

- Installation Process (In Settings):

```
Version: PICK LATEST
Architecture: x86_64
Threads: posix
Exception: seh
```

**If anyone is trying to add MinGW-w64 as a PATH variable and is not able to find the `gdb.exe` in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, <s>try looking for it in the Program files</s>.**

<s>`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`</s>

<s>The `gdb.exe` and other files are located in this directory.</s>

---

EDIT:

After making some changes in the launch.json file in VSCode, the MinGW-w64 GDB debugger started giving errors because there was 2 versions of MinGW in different folders i.e, MINGW and mingw64!

**It is essential that the installation path does not contain any spaces

(i.e., space in *"Program Files"*), this will create conflicts later.**

STEPS:

**1.** Uninstalled all the versions of GCC that was installed in the PC - Cygwin, MSYS2(32 bit) and mingw64(64 bit) and installed the MinGW-w64 again, this time using the MSYS2.

Please start afresh, if debugger is giving errors and if versions are clashing!

**2.** [Download](https://www.msys2.org/) the MSYS2 installer from this link.

Install process is simple, follow the steps mentioned in the website!

***It is essential that the installation path does not contain any spaces. Therefore, we cannot install MinGW-w64 in Program Files.***

**3.** After Installation is complete: Open MSYS2 terminal *(pink icon)*.

Update the package database and base packages using:

```
pacman -Syu
```

After this, Update rest of the base packages using:

```
pacman -Su
```

**4.** Now switch over to MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal *(blue icon)*.

To install gcc and g++ for C and C++.

For 64 bit:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

To install debugger (gdb).

For 64 bit:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

**5.** Now you're all SET!

Check versions:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
gdb --version
```

**6.** Finally, remove the old environment variables if any are left and add the new environment variable to the PATH!

BEFORE DEBUGGING FILES IN VSCode, MAKE SURE TO ADD -g tag while building, otherwise breakpoints will be ignored by the debugger!

**Footnote:**
It's very important to keep all the versions in one folder, if folders are different, then life will get tough later!

Answer (score 0):

I answered it in another post, you can check if you still get the error; [mingw-w64 installer "the file has been downloaded incorrectly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455927/mingw-w64-installer-the-file-has-been-downloaded-incorrectly/71554615#71554615)