# mingw-w64 says the file has been downloaded incorrectly

Tags: gcc, installation, mingw-w64

I just downloaded the mingw-w64 and tried to install it on my pc (windows 10) but I got an error message like "The file has been downloaded incorrectly", am I doing anything wrong? how can I fix this problem?
[image: here is a snap]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455927/mingw-w64-installer-the-file-has-been-downloaded-incorrectly Already answered

Answer (score 0):

Yup!, after hours of struggle I solved the problem.
if you getting that error message just do this

step 1: go to the [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)

step 2: download this one [image]

step 3: then extract the zip file and paste it into c drive and set the path variable.