# Error while installing MinGW-w64 .exe file for Widnows 11

Tags: c, installation, mingw-w64

I'm trying to install `MinGW-w64 compiler` for c lang on Windows 11 from this [sourceforge site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/). I downloaded the `.exe` file but when I go through the installer, and after setting the default path, it gives me this error: `The file has been downloaded incorrectly!`.
[image: A screen shot for the error message]

How I can fix this? Note: I downloaded the `.exe` file not the `zip` one.

Comment: The installer downloads other files. I guess one of them didn't download correctly. Also, this all looks pretty out-of-date. Have you visited the main MinGW-w64.org web site?

Comment: This is a FAQ, Mingw is seriously struggling with maintenance and the installation has been broken forever. Hang on and I'll dig up a duplicate question with a better download location...

Comment: If you follow the instructions from this answer in the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554615/584518 and download the executable from winlibs.com, it should work. Do not use official/sourceforge links.

Comment: @IanAbbott The problem is that the official version isn't maintained and the official site has been providing a broken executable build since forever. The only way to use the compiler is to download an alternative build from a mirror site. Open source in a nutshell...

Comment: @Lundin I've only used it via msys2, but would go with winlibs for a standalone installation. I guess those would be easier to set up with the horrid IDE that is VSCode?

Comment: @IanAbbott I only use mingw for quick & dirty testing on generic C stuff. Codeblocks was pretty much built to run mingw + gdb so that's what I use. Once you point it to the mingw64 installation directory, it will take care of all paths with some "automatic path" feature. No need to write some JSON or whatever VSC requires.

Comment: Thanks all. @Lundin I followed the link that you provide, and it works, very appreciate it.